# Java: may a child kill a parent?

Tags: java

In the snippet below ParentClass starts Controller then hides. 
It would be nice to be able to kill ParentClass on `jMenuItemExitActionPerformed.`
In retrospect I should have reversed the Parent/Child relationship, but that would be a big change at this point.
Is there a simpler way?

```
public class ParentClass extends javax.swing.JFrame {
    private void processC() {
        JFrame controller = new Controller();
        this.setVisible(false);
        ...
public class Controller extends javax.swing.JFrame {
    private void jMenuItemExitActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {                                                   
        System.exit(0);
        ...
```

Comment: No; matricide and patricide are illegal.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The easiest way would be to pass a reference to the parent, like so:

```
public class ParentClass extends javax.swing.JFrame {
    private void processC() {
        JFrame controller = new Controller(this);
        this.setVisible(false);
        ...
public class Controller extends javax.swing.JFrame {
    private ParentClass parent;
    public Controller(ParentClass parent) {
        this.parent = parent;
    }
    private void jMenuItemExitActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {                                                   
        parent.exit(); // or whatever
        System.exit(0);
        ...
```

Comment: Doesn't this make a circular reference (parent->child->parent...)? Adding a public static exit in ParentClass seems to work.

Comment: @JackN: You don't need to worry about the circular reference.  It won't cause any harm.  The GC is smart enough to figure it out.

Answer (score 1):

Reversing the Parent/Child relationship *is* the simpler way. If you don't, you will put so much time and effort into working around this problem, you will wish you'd just done it right to begin with.  You should always build things the way you know they need to be made.  The cost of time is well worth it.

Answer (score 1):

Adding a public static exit in ParentClass like this seems to work.

```
public class ParentClass extends javax.swing.JFrame { 
    private void processC() { 
        JFrame controller = new Controller(); 
        this.setVisible(false); 
        ... 
    public static void exit() {
        System.exit(0);
  ...
public class Controller extends javax.swing.JFrame { 
    private void jMenuItemExitActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {
        ParentClass.exit(); 
        ...
```

Comment: If your exit() method only calls System.exit(0) then you could keep your original code without any problems.  System.exit(0) will shut down the VM and automatically remove your ParentClass.